# How to use for loop in PHTML page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, phtml, programming

How to use for loop in phtml page i want to use the for loop in phtml page to complete my functionality

```
<php?
    for(i=1;1<=3;i++):

    //My code

endfor:
```

?>

I used as above code.

Answer (score 2):

[image: **enter image description here**]

```
  <span>How to use for loop in PHTML page</span>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  echo "The number is: $i <br>";
}
?>
```

[control-structures.for.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

**If you need to print custom html inside the cycle:**

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++): ?>
    <h1>test</h1>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

**Otherwise:**

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        echo $i;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of for loop, You can use foreach like:

```
<?php 

$variable = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6 );

$count = 1;
foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
    if($count >5){continue;}
        echo $value;
    $count++;
}
```

**Advantage**: in `foreach` loop you do need to check condition and increment operator. it will loop automatic for all elements

Comment: I need to run the loop 5 time only how can i specify it here

Comment: I need the condition checking and want to loop

Comment: You can add a count variable and check condition, please see my update answer.